# Matlab - Hough Transform detect harsh lines (not perfectly stright after binarize)

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect lines in a image using the Hough Transform. I almost get it, but the lines after binarize are a too harsh to be considered straight (see images, probably you need see them in full size). Is there any way (maybe some "bwmorph" operation) to soften the binarized lines, and make them straighter to be easier for the hough transform to detect them as a single line?

[image: Image which I aplly the Hough Transform]

[image: Resulting lines and binarized image]

My code right now is:

```
F=getframe;
I = rgb2gray(frame2im(F));
BW = imbinarize(I, 'adaptive', 'Sensitivity', 0.35);
BW = bwmorph(BW,'thin', inf);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to skeletonize first, but you do need to adjust your parameters for the hough transform, specifically how you want it to detect peaks and fill gaps. Here's an example of a transform I did on your figure (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html):

```
bw = (imbinarize(I, graythresh(I)));
dilatedImage = imdilate(bw,strel('disk',10));
thinnedImage = bwmorph(dilatedImage,'thin',inf);

[H,theta,rho] = hough(thinnedImage);
P = houghpeaks(H,20,'threshold',0);
lines = houghlines(thinnedImage,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',400,'MinLength',300);

figure, imshow(I), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You have no idea how much this answer helped me.